# Android configuration for camera "front" vs 'rear"

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an HTC One M8, and I have flashed cyanogen to it.
I am using it for testing some cameras that attach via the micro USB port.

When testing applications they seem to have a preference for front or rear, not a camera list, and assuming that different device models have different camera models, features, etc, I can only assume android provides some abstraction level between direct accessing the camera and the application. Furthermore is seems safe to assume that somewhere that is configured as front or rear respectively.

So the question is can that be edited, for instance a device has an internal camera that does not have the feature or resolution I need, can I plug one into the USB port, and change a configuration somewhere that says "when an application requests the *rear* camera, give it this one?"

Essentially can you edit somewhere what CAMERA_FACING_FRONT and CAMERA_FACING_BACK refers to on a hardware level?

I have looked and not be able to find much, and I do not compile my own android ROMS, so I am afraid it *may* end up being one of the reason ROMs are device specific because this is compiled into the OS and coded specifically for the camera native to *that* device, therefor not configurable, however if someone could nudge me in the correct direction that would be great.

Example, http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html states a call to open() on the Camera object returns the first rear facing camera. Something somewhere has instructed android what that camera is and that it is facing rear. It is specifically *that* configuration point I want to see if I can pick up and redirect. an example of why, I have an application that given the known size of something in the field of the camera, it can accurately measure distance to that object, it only does it through the rear camera, I want to try to make it do it through the thermal camera.

The third camera works fine on the device, and its native app consistently finds it (albeit not sure how or if it is a specific protocol over USB, driver, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

It appears the setting I am looking for is defined in the HAL https://source.android.com/devices/camera/index.html#implementing

> camera_common.h defines an important struct, camera_module, which
>   defines a standard structure to obtain general information about the
>   camera, such as its ID and properties that are common to all cameras
>   such as whether or not it is a front or back-facing camera.

Since this is modified in the header file and compiled into the kernel, then without hacking the ROM it would appear it is simply NOT configurable at any level outside a custom ROM.

Id est, I will never force another app into the camera of my choosing unless I choose to build a ROM to do it or without overly invasive hacking at the running ROM :-(